# TinyMCE Select text area by parent form ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, tinymce, tinymce-4

I was looking at http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:editor_selector

Is there a way to select a textbox only if it is under a `<form>` with a specific id?

For example:

```
<form id="edit_page">
    <textarea></textarea>
<form>
```

I know I can add a class to the text area to get it to work, but I'm hoping for this solution for my use case. As I'm using Active_admin and I don't want to have to redefine all the default forms for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using the tinyMCE jquery plugin, you can select the elements using the jquery selector($) and then call the tinymce function over that.

[Codepen example is here.](http://codepen.io/sujeetkrjaiswal/pen/xZJZJY)

JS Part:

```
$(function() {
  $('#edit_page2 textarea').tinymce({
    script_url : 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.3.4/tinymce.min.js',
    theme : "modern",
    mode : "textareas"
  });
});
```

HTML Part :

```
<form id="edit_page1">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
<form id="edit_page2">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
<form id="edit_page3">
    <textarea></textarea>
</form>
```

This will select based on the parent's id. You can use any type of css selector.
You will need to include jquery and tinyMce's jquery file

```
//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tinymce/4.3.4/jquery.tinymce.min.js
```